# Cross Domain jQuery Popup POST

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, post, cross-domain

I'm trying to make a cross domain POST using the following jQuery popup. IE gives me permission denied on Line 19 of jquery.min.js. Please note that I have the following script running on www.mysite.com and I'm trying to post the data to www.google.com for example. Thus making a cross domain post. I assume this is why IE is giving me permission denied. I know there should be a solution to create a hidden iframe but I have no idea how to implement this in my code. Some examples would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css" />
<style type="text/css">
#register { display: none; }
.ui-dialog { font-size: 10px; }
.ui-dialog .ui-dialog-titlebar-close { visibility: hidden; }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

function loadpopup(){

function Init() 
{
jQuery('#register').dialog({ width: 400, resizable: false, buttons: { "Continue": function() {
        if (jQuery("#email").val().length < 3) 
        {
            alert('Please enter your email address to continue.');
            jQuery("#email").focus();
        }
        else 
        {
            jQuery("#email_2").val(jQuery("#email").val());
            $.post("http://google.com/register.php", $("form[name='registerform']").serialize());
            jQuery('#register').dialog('close')}
    } 
}, closeOnEscape: false, modal: true, show: 'slide' });
}
jQuery(document).ready(Init);
}

loadpopup();

</script>
<div id="register">
<form>
<center>
<table><tbody>
<tr><td align="center" style="text-align: center; font-size: 10px; background: #FFFFFF;">
<br><h3>Register</h3>
  </td></tr>
<tr><td align="left" style="text-align: justify; font-size: 11px; background: #FFFFFF;">
Please enter your email address to continue.</br></br>
  </td></tr>
</tbody></table></center>
<center>
<div>
    <table>
        <tbody>
            <tr><td align="left" style="font-size: 12px; background: #FFFFFF;"><b>Email:</b></td><td align="left" style="background: #FFFFFF; font-size: 11px;"><input type="text" id="email" name="email" maxlength="26"/></td></tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
</form>
</center>
</div>
<form name="registerform" action="http://google.com/register.php" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="email_2" id="email_2" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are posting via XHR to a different domain. You can't do that because of [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy).

Instead, build the form and then call `submit()` on it.

The way you are doing it now, Google is returning `405 Method Not Allowed` which could be returned for a number of reasons.

Comment: I'm not making the post to google. The domain receiving the POST request is under my control. Can I not make my server accept it? I realize I wouldnt be able to get any return data but it just needs to POST and thats it. I know it's possible to bypass the same origin policy using an iframe but I have no clue how to go about doing this.

Comment: That's why I said and I quote "I'm trying to post the data to www.google.com for example..."

Comment: By this I meant to show that the post had to happen accross domains.